# Rails 4 - Where Attribute is Blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model

I have an `Article` model with a `short_answer` text column.

What is the best way to find all articles where the short_answer is blank?

I thought something like this would work:

```
Article.where(short_answer: nil)
```

But the short answer is not nil. It is just blank. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Article.where(short_answer: "")
```

Would do the trick

Comment: Easy enough. Thanks for the quick response. @Nermin